# Create Views return all columns from join

Tags: sql, view, sap-iq

I am getting an error in something that can be simplified to:

```
create view test as
select *
from 
  firsttable f
inner 
join  ( select *
    , row_number() as rownum
    from 
      secondtable s
   ) as t

on    f.id = t.id
```

The error is something along the lines of derived table t has no name for the first index. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Use this. Notice the `s.` before `*` in the select query of `secondtable`.

Also use column names and their appropriate alias as if both table as 2 columns with same name, then you might get error becuase of that.

```
create view test as
select f.id as id1,f.col1 as col1,f.col2 as col2 ......
       t.id as id2,t.col1 as tcol1,t.col2 as tcol2 .....
from 
  firsttable f
inner 
join  ( select s.*
    , row_number() as rownum
    from 
      secondtable s
   ) as t

on    f.id = t.id
```

Comment: thanks. now it gives error Derived table 'f' has no name for column 1

Comment: That may be due to similar column names. Try using aliases like I gave in the edited answer.

Comment: @toing - If it works for you, then please accept the answer by clicking on tick symbol on left of the answer so it could be closed.